# mysql concatenate columns if column is not null

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

Here is the table schema;

```
create table campaign (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    custom_param1 VARCHAR(15),
    custom_value1 VARCHAR(15),
    custom_param2 VARCHAR(15),
    custom_value2 VARCHAR(15),
    custom_param3 VARCHAR(15),
    custom_value3 VARCHAR(15),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and this is the mock data I have;

```
id  custom_param1   custom_value1   custom_param2   custom_value2   custom_param3   custom_value3
--  -------------   -------------   -------------   -------------   -------------   -------------
1   param1          value1          param2          value2          param3          value3
2   param1          value1          param2          value2          param3          value3
3   param1          value1          param2          value2          param3          value3
4   param1          value1          param2          value2          NULL            NULL
5   param1          value1          NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL
```

Now I am trying to concatenate params and values columns like a format

```
param1=value1; param2=value2, param3=value3
```

if a row has only two params and values it should be like;

```
param1=value1; param2=value2
```

well I create a query which I can concatenate row but if one of the is null then whole row is become a null - As I know if `concat` function tries to concat a NULL value string will completely become null. And this is query I use.

```
select CONCAT(c.custom_param1, '=', c.custom_value1, '; ',
                c.custom_param2, '=', c.custom_value2, '; ',
                c.custom_param3, '=', c.custom_value3) as 'Custom Parameters'
from campaign as c;
```

I will appreciate for any kind of help. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do if the value is null, you can try

```
SELECT CONCAT(
c.custom_param1, '=', IFNULL(c.custom_value1, ''), '; ',
c.custom_param2, '=', IFNULL(c.custom_value2, ''), '; ',
c.custom_param3, '=', IFNULL(c.custom_value3, ''), '; ') as 'Custom Parameters'
FROM campaign as c;
```

Will return

```
param1=value1; param2=value2; param3=;
```

Or you can exclude the whole value pair like this....

```
SELECT CONCAT(
IFNULL(CONCAT(c.custom_param1, '=', c.custom_value1, '; '), ''),
IFNULL(CONCAT(c.custom_param2, '=', c.custom_value2, '; '), ''),
IFNULL(CONCAT(c.custom_param3, '=', c.custom_value3, '; '), '')) AS 'Custom Parameters'
FROM campaign as c;
```

which will return

```
param1=value1; param2=value2;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Oh I guess I understand your solution, however, I am getting syntax error which I could not find.

Answer (score 1):

Use ifnull http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

```
select CONCAT(IFNULL(c.custom_param1, ''), '=', IFNULL(c.custom_value1, ''), '; ', IFNULL(c.custom_param2, ''), '=', IFNULL(c.custom_value2, ''), '; ', IFNULL(c.custom_param3, ''), '=', IFNULL(c.custom_value3,'')) as 'Custom Parameters' from campaign as c
```

You could change `IFNULL(c.custom_param1, '')` to `IFNULL(c.custom_param1, 'NULL')` or whatever you need.

Updated info `param1=value1; =; = which should be param1=value1` EDIT:

```
select
CONCAT(
    IF(c.custom_param1 IS NOT NULL AND c.custom_value1 IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(c.custom_param1, '=', c.custom_value1, '; '), ''),
    IF(c.custom_param2 IS NOT NULL AND c.custom_value2 IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(c.custom_param2, '=', c.custom_value2, '; '), ''),
    IF(c.custom_param3 IS NOT NULL AND c.custom_value3 IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(c.custom_param3, '=', c.custom_value3), '')
) as 'Custom Parameters'
from campaign as c
```

example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef859f/2/0

Comment: thanks for your help, however, it returns 0 columns as result. I didnt know there was if conditions in mysql though.

Comment: yep, fixed and given example in sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Use [ifnull](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/) to check if a column is null and replace it with blank:

```
select CONCAT(ifnull(c.custom_param1,""), '=', ifnull(c.custom_value1,""), '; ',
                ifnull(c.custom_param2,""), '=', ifnull(c.custom_value2,""), '; ',
                ifnull(c.custom_param3,""), '=', ifnull(c.custom_value3,"")) as 'Custom Parameters'
from campaign as c;
```

Update:

```
select CONCAT(ifnull(c.custom_value1,concat(c.custom_param1,"=",c.custom_value1), ifnull(c.custom_value2,concat(";",c.custom_param2,"=",c.custom_value2)...) as 'Custom Parameters'
    from campaign as c;
```

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for your answer. I tried your solution, however, if a column is null it still continues to concatenate. For example, for the 5th column result becomes `param1=value1; =; =` which should be `param1=value1` . I know it looks a little bit complicated

Answer (score 1):

Try below SQL

```
select CONCAT(IFNULL(c.custom_param1,''), '=', (IFNULL(c.custom_value1,''), '; ',
                (IFNULL(c.custom_param2,''), '=', (IFNULL(c.custom_value2,''), '; ',
                (IFNULL(c.custom_param3,''), '=', (IFNULL(c.custom_value3,'')) as 'Custom Parameters'
from campaign as c;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is somehow a syntax error. I guess about nested parenthesis. Could we use nested `ifnull` functions ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,CONCAT_WS( 
           COALESCE(CONCAT(custom_param1, custom_value1), ''),
           COALESCE(CONCAT(custom_param2,  custom_value2), ''),
           COALESCE(CONCAT(custom_param3, custom_value3), '')) campaign_survey
       FROM campaign;
```